# Adding React to a workspace failed, EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/mint/.cache/Cypress'

Tags: javascript, npm, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I am trying to add `@nrwl/react` on en empty nx workspace.

So i am creating an empty nx workspace with : `yarn create nx-workspace <app_name>`.

Then when i do a `yarn ng add @nrwl/react` to add React i have this error (even with sudo) :

```
> cypress@3.3.1 postinstall /home/mint/dev/Learn/Nx/my-app/node_modules/cypress
> node index.js --exec install

Cypress cannot write to the cache directory due to file permissions

See discussion and possible solutions at
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1281

----------

Failed to access /home/mint/.cache/Cypress:

EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/mint/.cache/Cypress'

----------

Platform: linux (Linux Mint - )
Cypress Version: 3.3.1
npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@8.0.1 requires a peer of @angular/compiler-cli@>=8.0.0-beta.0 < 9.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! cypress@3.3.1 postinstall: `node index.js --exec install`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the cypress@3.3.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/mint/.npm/_logs/2019-06-18T21_51_47_231Z-debug.log
Package install failed, see above.
Workspace creation failed, see above.
```

Manually installing Cypress on my local machine doesn't fixed the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try to create your app with:

```
sudo yarn create nx-workspace <app_name>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue and can't remember how I fixed it (should have written an answer). But it's always a bad idea to use `sudo` with Yarn or Npm.